# Convert a event handler in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have the following code.

```
$('.crossOutAnswer').on('click', function(){
  var crossStatus = $(this).hasClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer'),
      crossOutElement = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1].split('-')[1];
   if(crossStatus == 1){
     $(this).removeClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
     $('.res' + crossOutElement).removeClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
    $('.res' + crossOutElement).addClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
  }
})
```

It works OK, but what I'm trying to do is convert this in 2 functions

1. The first to do the first statement
2. The second to do the ELSE statement

The problem is that when I try to convert them as 2 functions, the $(this) stop working (for obvius reasons there is no trigger anymore).

Does anyone knows a best practice in how convert event handlers in functions?.

**EDIT**

Please note that I can pass the this parameter with no problems, but the variables get undefined then. So the solution must solve that issue WITHOUT redeclaring in the function

Comment: event handlers already are functions. Note the `function(){`

Comment: you could simply store the reference to this in a variable at the beginning of the click handler. var elem = $(this);

Comment: Note that relying on the order of classes in the `class` attribute is incredibly easily broken. I would suggest storing any required meta data in a `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer. In this way, you don't need to redeclare the variables and the 'this' works OK.

```
  $('.crossOutAnswer').on('click', function(){
      var crossStatus = $(this).hasClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer'),
          crossOutElement = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1].split('-')[1];
       if(crossStatus == 1){ removeCrossOut(this, crossStatus, crossOutElement); }
       else{ addCrossOut(this, crossStatus, crossOutElement); }
    })

    function removeCrossOut(elem, crossStatus, crossOutElement){
        $(elem).removeClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
        $('.res' + crossOutElement).removeClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
    }

    function addCrossOut(elem, crossStatus, crossOutElement){
        $(elem).addClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
        $('.res' + crossOutElement).addClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

***First:***

You can pass the `this` as parameter to the functions, like this:

```
if(crossStatus == 1){
    functionA(this);
}else{
    functionB(this);
}
```

And using it:

```
functionA(remoteThis){
    $(remoteThis).doSomething();
}
```

***Second:***

You can call those functions using `apply()` and passing `this` as a context, so that those functions will have the same `this` context, like this:

```
if(crossStatus == 1){
    functionA.apply(this);
}else{
    functionB.apply(this);
}
```

And using it:

```
functionA(){
    $(this).doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing a reference to `this` should do the trick... unless I'm missing something

```
$('.crossOutAnswer').on('click', function(){
  var crossStatus = $(this).hasClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer'),
    crossOutElement = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1].split('-')[1];
  if(crossStatus == 1){
    method1(this,crossOutElement );
  }else{
    method2(this,crossOutElement );
  }
})

function method1(elem,crossOutElement ){
    $(elem).removeClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
    $('.res' + crossOutElement).removeClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
}

function method2(elem,crossOutElement ){
    $(elem).addClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
    $('.res' + crossOutElement).addClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
}
```

Comment: It look great... but there is just a little problem :( console thrwos me that  "crossOutElement is not defined" -- Is there a way method 1 and 2 could recognize the variables initialized in the eventHandler? That could answer the question (:

Comment: You can either pass them along the same way as you pass `this` as param or declare them in a namespace containing all those functions (above those functions).

Comment: Sorry @LesterVargas, I'll add the changes for that, though I'm sure you've gotten to that point already.

Answer (score 1):

You will solve your problem by passing reference to **this** as parameter:

```
function f1(myThis) {
    $(myThis).removeClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
    $('.res' + crossOutElement).removeClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
}

function f2(myThis) {
    $(myThis).addClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer');
    $('.res' + crossOutElement).addClass('CrossedOutQuestion');
}

$('.crossOutAnswer').on('click', function(){
    var crossStatus = $(this).hasClass('alreadyCrossOutAnswer'),
    crossOutElement = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1].split('-')[1];

    if(crossStatus == 1){
        f1(this);
    } else {
        f2(this);
    }
});
```